# Unable to click on the main form when using TThread.WaitFor

Tags: delphi

This is my example code, I use `Waitfor` to wait for a thread finish

```
TCPThread = class(TThread)
protected
    procedure Execute; override;
public
    Source, Dest: String;
    FHandle:THandle;
    constructor Create(Source1, Dest1: string; TFHandle1: THandle);
end;

............

constructor TCPThread.Create(Source1, Dest1: string; TFHandle1: THandle);
begin
      inherited Create(False);
      Source:=Source1;
      Dest:=Dest1;
      FHandle:=TFHandle1;
end;

procedure TCPThread.Execute;
var
    Cancel : PBool;
begin
    Cancel := PBOOL(False);
    CopyFileEx(PChar(Source), PChar(Dest), @CopyFileProgress, Pointer(FHandle), Cancel, 0);
end;
```

The progress bar is working well, but I can not click on any button and anywhere, e.g cancel button.

I need to wait for the files to be copied or can cancel it if necessary and cleanup

```
CPThread := TCPThread.Create('D:\test.iso', 'D:\test2.iso',FHandle);
CPThread.WaitFor;
CPThread.Destroy;
```

Comment: If you are going to ***WAIT*** for the the thread to finish before doing anything else, what do you expect to happen?

Comment: @Craig check it and continue

Comment: To "wait" means to stay in place until something happens. So in this case the current stops in place. It _waits for_ CPThread to finish before it continues to the next instruction. This is the most pointless way to use thread, because you are actively preventing both threads running at the same time.

Comment: If the first thread is terminated, it required second thread to terminate and If I can click the button to cancel both threads will be terminated.

Comment: I need to wait for the files to be copied or can cancel it if necessary and cleanup

Comment: If you are waiting then what is the point of the thread. You need to stop waiting. Keep the thread. Don't wait. Have the thread signal the main thread when it is finished. For instance by sending a message or OnTerminate or TThread.Synchronize etc.

Comment: I wonder how do you suppose to change the local boolean when you press cancel.

Comment: BTW, asking a question will help getting an answer.

Comment: Indeed, I don't see a question, only a bunch of requirements.

Comment: @sertac it's not even a Boolean. It's a PBool assigned the value nil!

Comment: @David - Indeed. Shouldn't that be an AV than when the OS tries to dereference the value? Ah, looked at the docs, it's optional. Just disregarded here.

Comment: @Sertac it sends a message to abort this process through CopyFileProgress function

Comment: @nguyentu - Ok. In that case just pass nil for pbCancel and the code will not confuse me. :)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`TThread.WaitFor()` blocks the calling thread until the thread is terminated.  When called in the context of the main UI thread, `WaitFor()` does not process pending window messages (but does process pending `TThread.Synchronize()` and `TThread.Queue()` requests).  That is why you cannot click on anything.

For what you are attempting to do, don't wait on the thread at all.  Let it run normally while you return control back to the main UI message loop, and let the thread tell you when it is finished with its work.

Also, you are misusing the `pbCancel` parameter of `CopyFileEx()`.

Try something more like this:

```
type
  TCPThread = class(TThread)
  private
    Cancel : BOOL;
    Source, Dest: String;
    FHandle: THandle;
  protected
    procedure Execute; override;
    procedure TerminatedSet; override;
  public
    constructor Create(Source1, Dest1: string; TFHandle1: THandle);
  end;

constructor TCPThread.Create(Source1, Dest1: string; TFHandle1: THandle);
begin
  inherited Create(True);
  FreeOnTerminate := True;
  Source := Source1;
  Dest := Dest1;
  FHandle := TFHandle1;
end;

procedure TCPThread.Execute;
begin
  if not CopyFileEx(PChar(Source), PChar(Dest), @CopyFileProgress, Pointer(FHandle), @Cancel, 0) then
    ReturnValue := GetLastError;
end;

procedure TCPThread.TerminatedSet;
begin
  Cancel := True;
end;
```

```
var
  CPThread: TCPThread = nil;

procedure TMyForm.CopyButtonClick(Sender: TObject);
begin
  CPThread := TCPThread.Create('D:\test.iso', 'D:\test2.iso', FHandle);
  CPThread.OnTerminate := CopyFinished;
  CPThread.Start;
  CopyButton.Enabled := False;
  CancelButton.Enabled := True;
end;

procedure TMyForm.CancelButtonClick(Sender: TObject);
begin
  if CPThread <> nil then
    CPThread.Terminate;
end;

procedure TMyForm.CopyFinished(Sender: TObject);
begin
  CPThread := nil;
  CancelButton.Enabled := False;

  if TCPThread(Sender).FatalException <> nil then
  begin
    // thread terminated by uncaught exception, do something...
  end
  else if TCPThread(Sender).ReturnValue <> 0 then
  begin
    // CopyFileEx() failed, do something...
  end
  else
  begin
    // CopyFileEx() succeeded, do something...
  end

  CopyButton.Enabled := True;
end;
```